# Using SignerSignEx2 with a CNG provider

Tags: cng, authenticode

We currently set the `SignerSignEx2`'s `SIGNER_PROVIDER_INFO` to a suitable CSP, however, the docs say that CSPs are outdated and we're now using our vendor's CNG provider instead. We could migrate all our other usages, except the `SignerSignEx2` call. How to specify that the key used for signing the DLL should come from a CNG provider and not from a CSP?